# Issue with width of an image CSS

Tags: css

I have a couple of images that I'm trying to use. The height in CSS adjusts but whenever I try to change the width to anything over 183px (probably specific to my image) it simply doesn't work.

```css
.mobile-nav {
  display: block;
}

.mobile-nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mobile-nav-img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 39px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div className='mobile-nav'>
  <a className='mobile-nav-link' href='http://www.google.com'>
    <img className='mobile-nav-img' src={require( 'image1.png')} />
  </a>
  <a className='mobile-nav-link' href='http://www.google.com'>
    <img className='mobile-nav-img' src={require( 'image2.png')} />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

when styling images don't use `height` value to the image because it will stretch the original size. You always use `width` property for the image. And to auto shrink in doing doing responsive just add `max-width:100%` to the image.

```
.mobile-nav-img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 183px;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: The thing with adjusting the width instead of height is I have several images that need to be the same height but are different widths. I want the images to just vary in width but maintain their height

Answer (score 2):

Just change `object-fit: contain` to `object-fit: cover` and it should work

```
.mobile-nav-img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 39px;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The image tag itself has an attribute called `width=""`.

[Link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp)

Comment: I tried it but the img width is still capped at 183px for some reason